# button calls the method of another button in the same form

Tags: javascript, php

I have two buttons in the same form :

```
<form id="form" name="form">
    <input id="check" type="submit" value="Check" name="check">
    <input id="add" type="submit" value="Add/ Modify" name="add">
</form>
```

and

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
var tmp=$("#form").serialize();
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "config.php",
  data: tmp + '&action=add',
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(res){
    window.alert(res);
  }
});
e.preventDefault();
});


$("#form").submit(function(e){
var tmp=$("#form").serialize();
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "config.php",
  data: tmp + '&action=check',
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(res){
    window.alert(res);
  }
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

and then finally:

```
switch($_POST['action'])
{
    case 'check':
    print_r("check");
    break;

    case 'add':
    print_r("add");
    break;
}
```

and my problem is that when I click on one button, both method are called. I tried this but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. 
Thank you !

Comment: both buttons have `type=submit` therefore both buttons are causing the `onsubmit` event to fire...

Comment: Both are of `type="submit"` and therefore will trigger any on submit action bound to the form.

Comment: Why do you need two submit functions on the form? You can use just one....You are also POST-ing twice...

Comment: above the buttons, I have fields that can be filled, and I need the infos when submitting both buttons. What should I change ? :)

Comment: The first thing I would change is... get a basic understanding of the technology you are slaughtering

Comment: mmh ok sorry, I never studied php nor javascript, I'm just trying to help a friend for an urgent project.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor I've following examples found on stack overflow where two buttons have submit type, but not the same name, and that's how you can distinguish them

Comment: ok, well that's what's causing the problem. i don't know what to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the type from `submit` to `button`, and add a class on them to create a 'click' handler. In this callback, you could call your function with a parameter, the name of button:

```
<form id="form" name="form">
  <input id="check" type="button" value="Check" name="check" class="submitter">
  <input id="add" type="button" value="Add/ Modify" name="add" class="submitter">
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(".submitter").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  formSubmitted(this.name);
});

function formSubmitted(action){ // One function, with action in paramter
  var tmp=$("#form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "config.php",
    data: tmp + '&action='+action, 
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(res){
      window.alert(res);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Only one drawback with that: submitting the form hitting Enter won't work with buttons. You could however add a hidden form field with a default value and change it on click.

Comment: @masterfloda Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @masterfloda You can add an event listener to submit the form on the "enter" key. This is quite common and done all the time.